# Cannot open with built in administrator account - Windows 10 Pro - Domain User

Tags: windows, windows-10, domain, uac

A few new laptops on our domain have come with Windows 10 Pro.

Every week or so users will report issues with opening in built Windows apps, they will get the message;

*"Cannot open with built in administrator account"*

I have tried the solution given here - https://4sysops.com/archives/why-the-built-in-administrator-account-cant-open-edge-and-a-lesson-in-uac/ but that will work for a few days and revert back.

There are no Group Policies set at the moment that touch the UAC side of things at the moment.

Comment: Don't give them administrative accounts? If it reverts someone is doing something to revert it.

Comment: They aren't local admin, I have been using a test laptop and user with no admin privledges and it does the same thing.

Comment: Did you check by e.g. trying to modify the hosts file? Just in case something bogus is going on and even normal users do get those privileges? What apps did you use and how did you start them?

Comment: Edge, Calculator, ToDoList, Settings and a few others. Just opened through the start menu.